# MySQL find double bookings in hotel database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with an assignment for school. I've only been doing SQL for 2 months and can't figure this out. My teacher gave me some hints about using self joins. The database has 3 more tables, but I don't think they are needed here.

The assignment is to write a query that will help hotel staff find double bookings (same room, same date). I've made a test database that has a double booking to control the query.

```sql
drop database if exists hoteltest;
create database hoteltest;
use hoteltest;

create table Roomreservation(
    ResNr int not null,
    RoomNr int not null,
    FromDate date not null,
        ToDate date not null,
    primary key (ResNr, RoomNr, FromDate)
    );
    
    
insert into Roomreservation
values
     (51, 102, '2008-12-05', '2008-12-07'),
     (51, 103, '2008-12-05', '2008-12-07'),
     (51, 104, '2008-12-05', '2008-12-09'),
     (52, 201, '2008-12-05', '2008-12-14'),
     (53, 102, '2008-12-04', '2008-12-10');
     
select * from Roomreservation;
```

Does anyone have a good and easy solution for this?

Honestly, I'm kinda stuck, I've been trying different solutions with concat_ws and the dates but with no results.

Comment: _"the assignment is to write a query that will help hotel staff find double bookings"_ - wrly, I note this could be a trick-question, because a well-designed database with the right constraints set-up _won't allow_ double-booking to happen in the first-place.

Comment: `primary key (ResNr, RoomNr, FromDate)` - I assume a reservation's details are mutable, such as the booking date range - in which case you shouldn't use `FromDate` in the composite PK.

Comment: "I've made a test database...."  Why do you use dates from 14 year ago when creating a test database (or did you really copy/paste it from the question....) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the range of Fromdate and todate. For this, you can use [between](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_between.asp). You also exclude the same row from the join. And you only extract one from the join since AxB will lead to BxA on the join. Therefore :

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Roomreservation t1
JOIN Roomreservation t2 ON t1.ResNr<>t2.ResNr AND t1.RoomNr=t2.RoomNr AND (t1.FromDate BETWEEN t2.FromDate AND t2.ToDate OR t2.FromDate BETWEEN t1.FromDate AND t1.ToDate);
```

You should use an auto-incremented primary key, such as something as the resnumber but unique.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is excactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to join the table on itself, looking for 2 records where the `ResNo` is different, the `RoomNr` is the same, and either the `FromDate` or the `ToDate` is between the other record's `FromDate`-`ToDate`.

I could write the query for you, but i believe in self-learning, especially for school assignments (rather than actual work).

NOTE: don't get lazy when it comes to naming, e.g. `ResNr` -> `ReservationNumber`
will save you more time in the future when reading queries

Answer (score 0):

There is a, or at least a, double booking on the following dates:

| RoomNr | d | count(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 2008-12-04 | 2 |
| 102 | 2008-12-05 | 2 |
| 102 | 2008-12-06 | 2 |
| 102 | 2008-12-07 | 2 |
| 102 | 2008-12-08 | 2 |
| 102 | 2008-12-09 | 2 |
| 102 | 2008-12-10 | 2 |
| 102 | 2008-12-11 | 2 |
| 102 | 2008-12-12 | 2 |
| 102 | 2008-12-13 | 2 |
| 102 | 2008-12-14 | 2 |

```sql
WITH recursive dates as (
    select min(FromDate)  as d FROM Roomreservation
    union all
    select adddate(d, INTERVAL 1 day) 
    from dates 
    where d<(select max(ToDate) from Roomreservation)
)
SELECT 
   RoomNr,
   d,
   count(*)
FROM Roomreservation
CROSS JOIN dates
GROUP BY 
  RoomNr,
  d
HAVING count(*) >1
ORDER BY d, RoomNr
```

- The `WITH recursive....` is creating a table (`dates`) with all dates from the lower value of FromDate to the highest value of ToDate.
- And then it's just a matter of counting how many reservation there are on that day, for that RoomNr.

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/SsROByte)